# Multi-dimensional Feynman Kac Theorem

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to understand how to prove the multi-dimensional version of the Feynman-Kac formula. The single-dimensional version is proved on this page:

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman–Kac_formula

However, here the multi-dimensional version is merely stated. I had little luck trying to prove it myself and when I tried to find a proof, I only got a few pdf's that just (again) stated it.

Could someone please suggest a reference from where I can understand a proof of this?

(P.S. The hyperlink code is not working for some reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula#cite_note-1 they reference as having a proof

Pham, Huyên (2009). Continuous-time stochastic control and optimisation with financial applications. Springer-Verlag

Comment: Thanks! But I had tried to find that book already on the net, no luck..

Comment: @ul15524, I have written a proof for a case that is multi-dimensional, as well as being somewhat generalised in other ways from what is on the wiki page. It suffers from two gaps that the wiki one-dimensional proof also has, which I am working to fill in. But it's at least as complete as the wiki one-dimensional proof. The proof's in latex/pdf. If you're still interested let me know and I'll send it (it's too long to post it here)